# Check functions result inside if statement Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got three functions and errors on AddMopsScores if statement. I want to check - did the user and his partner has more than 10 scores, if yes - add 5 more for both users. But if statement not works, so I need to fix it.

```
/*
CREATE FUNCTION CountUserTasksForDay(integer) RETURNS INT AS '
    declare userTasksCount integer;
    begin
    SELECT into userTasksCount COUNT(*) FROM "UserScoreAttainment"
    WHERE "UserId" = $1
    AND "Date" BETWEEN ''2021-01-06'' AND ''2021-01-07''
    AND "Score" = 1;
    return userTasksCount;
    END'  language plpgsql;
    */

/*
CREATE FUNCTION InsertMopsScore(INTEGER, INTEGER) RETURNS BIT AS 
'
begin
INSERT INTO public."UserScoreAttainment"(
    "UserId", "ReasonObjectId", "Date", "CourseId", "Reason", "Score")
    VALUES($1, $2, ''2021-01-06 18:43:03.883408'', 17, 4, 5);
    return 1;
end
'  language plpgsql;*/

CREATE FUNCTION AddMopsScores(INTEGER) RETURNS BIT AS '
    declare mopsId integer;
begin
    SELECT into mopsId "MOPSId" FROM "User"
    WHERE "Id" = $1
    
    IF(CountUserTasksForDay($1)>10 AND CountUserTasksForDay(mopsId)>10)
        InsertMopsScore($1, mopsId)
        InsertMopsScore(mopsId, $1)
    return 1;
end
' language plpgsql;

SELECT * AddMopsScores(2757)
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe IF statement not works, how can I fix it?

Comment: "Not works" is not a useful description...

Comment: Most of the IF statement is missing, you could add that part. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Got an error - Syntax error at or near "(" line InsertMopsScore($1, mopsId). I think It is not really descriptive

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) I found the reason why and changed a statement to

```
   IF(CountUserTasksForDay($1)>10 AND CountUserTasksForDay(mopsId)>10)
   THEN
        PERFORM InsertMopsScore($1, mopsId);
        PERFORM InsertMopsScore(mopsId, $1);
   END IF;
```